# How do I get a single word from a website/dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm currently trying to get a single word from a dictionary [website](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain).

I want to save that word as a string to later translate it into another language.
Here is the code I tried:

```
import random
from translate import Translator
import requests

response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()

random_line = random.choice(WORDS)
translator = Translator(to_lang="German")
translation = translator.translate(str(random_line))

print("Word: " + str(random_line))
print("Translation: " + str(translation))
```

Output:

```
Word: b'cleric'
Translation:  B&#39;cleric &#39;
```

How can I get rid of the other characters so that it translates correctly:

```
Word: cleric
Translation: Kleriker
```

Comment: Hi, please include the import statements that will [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your code. I'm sure one of the modules imported is `requests` but I'm not sure where `Translator` is coming from. Am I correct in assuming that it's from [`py_translator`](https://pypi.org/project/py-translator/)?

Comment: Oh sry forgot about that. Imports are: import requests, from translate import Translator

Comment: you get an output with apostrophes. you need to use encode()/decode() for these byte strigs. i.e. b'cleric'.decode() = 'cleric', 'cleric'.encode()=b'cleric'. seems like you need to decode() your random_line before you put it into your translator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a byte-like object, not a string. You can convert bytes to string using the `.decode` method:

```
import random
from translate import Translator
import requests

response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()

random_line = random.choice(WORDS).decode('utf-8')
translator = Translator(to_lang="German")
translation = translator.translate(random_line)

print("Word: " + random_line)
print("Translation: " + translation)
```

But actually, I'm not sure if this is what you want because the translator returns Geistlicher, not Kleriker

Comment: Thank you your comment was very helpful :) The translation Kleriker basically means the same as Geistlicher. But that's just something with the translator.